How do I study the performance of eBPF helper function calls?
I'm new to eBPF and, in my journey of learning about the eBPF universe, I have taken particular interest in studying its approach to synchronization in eBPF maps.
I have learned that if the kernel is compiled with BTF information, tools such as bpftop and bpftool prog profile can be used to gather statistics about a loaded eBPF program such as how many times it was called, number of cycles and instructions (and more), however this is used to profile the entire program.
Is there any publicly available tool that can collect data for a specific helper function call inside the program such as bpf_map_lookup_elem()?
The solution I had in mind in case no such tool is available was to use something like RDTSC in the kernel source code to evaluate the performance cost for each helper call, but I'm not sure this is the easiest or most recommendable way of doing so.

What about having a BPF program that only calls the helper and then benchmarking that program?

@pchaigno Since I am trying to study how adequate RCU is as a synchronization algorithm for concurrent map accesses, I figured a fair benchmark would benefit from a realistic use of map lookup/update operations that creates a high concurrency scenario (using an existing BCC tool, for example). I could make a program that only calls the bpf_map_lookup_elem helper and benchmark it, but would that represent a realistic use case?

Got it! Then maybe one option would be to attach another BPF program to the kernel function(s) corresponding to bpf_map_lookup_elem to measure the latency.

Sorry for the late answer, but I ended up using ftrace's function_graph tracer to get bpf_map_lookup_elem latency measurements
